# WSTP/MathLink: Transfering long lists (that require 64bit for index range)

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I am using WSTP to call external C-Code from a Mathematica 10.2 session on a Linux-x86-64 system. The routine `WSGetReal64List(WSLINK link,double **a,long *n)` seems to require the length n to be 32 bit.

Is there any alternative to `WSGetReal64List()` that allows to read lists with index range of 64 bit?

Comment: I would expect long to be 64-bit on 64-bit Linux.

Comment: You are right, I was confused. After looking deeper I found the problem occurs in `WSReleaseReal64List(WSLINK link,double *a,int n)` which now requires n to be 32 bit and seems to cause a `$FAILED` if `n` exceeds `2^31-1`. The failure can also be observed in the pre-built example `sumalist`, where `SumAList[ConstantArray[1,2^31-1]]` works, but not `SumAList[ConstantArray[1,2^31]]`.

Comment: @ilian Actually all these functions seem to take an `int`, and a `long` would be 32 on Windows anyway.  Does MathLink support arrays that require 64-bit indexing?  LibraryLink does.  I don't actually need this, I don't have that much memory (for a real array, it would take 16 GB).  I'm just curious.